# How to extract date , month and year from the date we pass to javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have two date fields: `FROM` and `TO`. I am trying to pass the date to JavaScript so that I can compare the dates and month of the two dates entered.

I am getting the date using

```
var date= document.getElementById("fromdate").value;
```

Here I am getting the date from an element in the form of `yyyy-mm-dd`. Now I am trying to extract the date, month and year individually for some comparison.

I am using `var month=date.getMonth();` but it's not working.

Comment: The value is a String, so calling Date methods on it isn't going to work. You can get the parts as an array using `var parts = value.split('-')`.

Comment: There is no date object in the code you shared. You need to either convert the string into a date object, or split the string into the parts you need.

Comment: Ok guys splitting it out will be better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because you can't get data directly from a string, you first must create a new `Date` object using your string, then you'll be able to manipulate it.

```
var myDate = new Date(document.getElementById("fromdate").value);
myDate.getMonth();
```

Also note that your `yyyy-mm-dd` format may not work for all browsers since all of them interpret javascript differently (It does work in chrome though).  Just something to be mindful of.

Comment: let me try it victor

Comment: Please don't suggest parsing strings with the Date constructor. It is unreliable and will remain so at least until ECMA-262 ed 6 is ubiquitous (it isn't yet), and even then only for certain ISO formats.

Comment: @RobG, how else would you manipulate dates without pulling in a library like moment.js?  Suppose somebody wanted to take a date in string format and find the date 100 days from now... I don't see a more reliable solution to problems like that.

Comment: @VictorJohnson—whether conversion to a Date or just using the string parts is more appropriate is up to the OP. The question was for the parts. To parse the OP format is 2 lines of code (which includes validating the date), I find it difficult to justify a library for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

create a date object using the string..

```
var date= document.getElementById("fromdate").value;
var obj=new Date(date);
```

and use

```
obj.getFullYear();
```

to get Year....

use

```
obj.getMonth();
```

to get Month.

use

```
obj.getDate();
```

to get day..

Note : note that your yyyy-mm-dd format may not work for all browsers  every browser interpret js differently..

so its' better to split and use..

like

```
var date= document.getElementById("fromdate").value;
var res=date.split('-');
```

`res[0]` contains Year.
`res[1]` contains Month.
`res[2]` contains Date.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function splitDate(date){
  var result = date.split('-');
  return result;
  
}

var splittedDate = splitDate('2015-07-09');
var year = splittedDate[0];
var month = splittedDate[1];
var day = splittedDate[2];
alert(year);
alert(month);
alert(day);
```